# Python 3 - How to chmod all files in a given directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, chmod

In a python 3 script I'm trying to add execution permissions to all .sh files in a directory, as follows:

```
from os import chmod
chmod('/path_to_dir/dir_prefix_*/bin/*.sh',0o755)
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'/path_to_dir/dir_prefix_*/bin/*.sh'
```

If I run this chmod from bash, it works ok, so I guess python's chmod does not like the use of `*` in the path.

What would be the correct way to chmod all .sh files in a directory then?

Comment: Pythond can't use `*` to get all files - you wlll have to use loop to get all folder with prefix `dir_prefix_` and later use another loop to get all files with extension `.sh` in folder. Eventually you should first use `glob.glob()` which can use `*`

Answer (score 0):

Just use a for loop.

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("/mydir"):
    if file.endswith(".sh"):
        chmod(file, mode)
```

Comment: I believe it should b e chmod(os.path.join('/mydir',file)),mode)

Comment: Thanks. Please note that there's another `*` in the path, since there are multiple directories with the same prefix, and inside them there's the bin directory containing the .sh files. I guess I'd have to do another loop then? There's no way to do a one-liner like in regular chmod?

Comment: You can execute shell commands in python with the os.system() command. Maybe something like this, not really sure about the best chmod command: os.system("chmod -R 755 /path/to/directory")

Comment: instead of `os.listdir(..)` you could try to use `glob.glob('/path_to_dir/dir_prefix_*/bin/*.sh')` to get all files and later use `for`-loop with `chmod`

Comment: Thank you all! I wanted to do it from Python itself but I guess it's less effort to call a process and do the one-liner.